# How to extract first 2 words from a string in R?

Tags: r, string

I need to extract first 2 words from a string. If the string contains more than 2 words, it should return the first 2 words else if the string contains less than 2 words it should return the string as it is.

I've tried using 'word' function from stringr package but it's not giving the desired output for cases where len(string) < 2.

```
word(dt$var_containing_strings, 1,2, sep=" ")
```

Example:
Input String: Auto Loan (Personal)
Output: Auto Loan

Input String: Others
Output: Others

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use `stringr::word()`, you can do:

```
ifelse(is.na(word(x, 1, 2)), x, word(x, 1, 2))

[1] "Auto Loan" "Others"
```

Sample data:

```
x <- c("Auto Loan (Personal)", "Others")
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use regex in base R using `sub`

```
sub("(\\w+\\s+\\w+).*", "\\1", "Auto Loan (Personal)")
#[1] "Auto Loan"
```

which will also work if you have only one word in the text

```
sub("(\\w+\\s+\\w+).*", "\\1", "Auto")
#[1] "Auto"
```

Explanation :

Here we extract the pattern shown inside round brackets which is `(\\w+\\s+\\w+)` which means :

`\\w+` One word followed by `\\s+` whitespace followed by `\\w+` another word, so in total we extract two words. Extraction is done using backreference `\\1` in `sub`.

Comment: Can you please explain this part- \\w+\\s+\\w+).*", "\\1" in detail?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
a <- "this is a character string"

unlist(strsplit(a, " "))[1:2]

[1] "this" "is"
```

EDIT:
To add the part where original string is returned if number of worlds is less than 2, a simple if-else function can be used:

```
a <- "this is a character string"

words <- unlist(strsplit(a, " "))

if (length(words) > 2) {
  words[1:2]
} else {
  a
}
```